# Convert string to int, making a geo point

Tags: android, string, int, geo

I have a file with gps coords in every line:

```
9.34669876098644,48.2405319213867
9.36384963989269,48.2296714782715
9.3639497756958,48.2259712219238
9.36956977844238,48.2260589599609
9.36404991149908,48.2222709655763
9.36975955963135,48.2186508178712
```

now I want to parse the file and make geo points. First I open the file and read the line, than I split the line and want to make the string to an int. But than i got an NullPointerException after Log.d("4:",point_t[0] + " - " + point_t[1]);

```
try{
    InputStream koord = getAssets().open("bib.txt");
    if (koord != null) {
        InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(koord);
        BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(input);
        Log.d("2: ", "Read File");
        String line;
        while (( line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.d("3: ", line);
            String[] point_t = line.split(",");
            Log.d("4:",point_t[0] + " - " + point_t[1]);
            int x = Integer.parseInt(point_t[0]);
            int y = Integer.parseInt(point_t[1]);
            Log.d("Geopoint:",x + " - " + y);
            points.add(new GeoPoint((int)(x*1e6), (int)(y*1e6)));
            Log.d("5:","saved");
        }
        koord.close();
        polygon = new Polygon(points);
    }
}catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}  

06-20 08:45:21.701: E/ActivityThread(231): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
06-20 08:45:21.711: E/ActivityThread(231): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
06-20 08:45:21.721: E/ActivityThread(231): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
06-20 08:45:21.971: D/dalvikvm(231): GC freed 3008 objects / 190136 bytes in 60ms
06-20 08:45:22.071: D/Checkpoint:(231): Start ArrayList
06-20 08:45:22.081: I/global(231): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
06-20 08:45:22.081: D/Checkpoint:(231): Read File
06-20 08:45:22.081: D/Checkpoint:(231): 9.34669876098644,48.2405319213867
06-20 08:45:22.081: D/Point:(231): 9.34669876098644 - 48.2405319213867
06-20 08:45:22.161: I/MapActivity(231): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
06-20 08:45:22.171: E/MapActivity(231): Couldn't get connection factory client
06-20 08:45:22.381: D/dalvikvm(231): GC freed 983 objects / 342808 bytes in 62ms
06-20 08:45:22.391: D/AndroidRuntime(231): Shutting down VM
06-20 08:45:22.401: W/dalvikvm(231): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
06-20 08:45:22.401: E/AndroidRuntime(231): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
06-20 08:45:22.425: E/AndroidRuntime(231): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 08:45:22.425: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.draw(OverlayBundle.java:42)
06-20 08:45:22.425: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onDraw(MapView.java:476)
06-20 08:45:22.425: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6535)
06-20 08:45:22.425: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
06-20 08:45:22.425: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
06-20 08:45:22.425: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
06-20 08:45:22.425: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
06-20 08:45:22.425: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6641)
06-20 08:45:22.425: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
06-20 08:45:22.425: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
06-20 08:45:22.425: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
06-20 08:45:22.425: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
06-20 08:45:22.425: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
06-20 08:45:22.425: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
06-20 08:45:22.425: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
06-20 08:45:22.425: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
06-20 08:45:22.425: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
06-20 08:45:22.425: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
06-20 08:45:22.425: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
06-20 08:45:22.425: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1830)
06-20 08:45:22.425: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1349)
06-20 08:45:22.425: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1114)
06-20 08:45:22.425: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
06-20 08:45:22.425: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-20 08:45:22.425: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-20 08:45:22.425: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
06-20 08:45:22.425: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-20 08:45:22.425: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-20 08:45:22.425: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
06-20 08:45:22.425: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
06-20 08:45:22.425: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-20 08:45:22.442: I/dalvikvm(231): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
06-20 08:45:22.461: I/dalvikvm(231): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-20 08:45:24.701: I/Process(231): Sending signal. PID: 231 SIG: 9
```

@stuckless

```
Log.d("1: ", "Start ArrayList");
ArrayList<GeoPoint> points = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
try{
    InputStream koord = getAssets().open("bib.txt");
    if (koord != null) {
        InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(koord);
        BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(input);
        Log.d("2: ", "Read File");
        String line;
        while (( line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.d("3: ", line);
            String[] point_t = line.split(",");
            Log.d("4:",point_t[0] + " - " + point_t[1]);
            double x = Double.parseDouble(point_t[0]);
            double y = Double.parseDouble(point_t[1]);
            Log.d("Geopoint:",x + " - " + y);
            points.add(new GeoPoint((int)(x*1e6), (int)(y*1e6)));
            Log.d("5:","saved");
        }
        koord.close();
        polygon = new Polygon(points);
    }
}catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("APP","Failed", e);
    }        
    mapView.getOverlays().clear();
    mapView.getOverlays().add(polygon);
    mapView.invalidate();
}
```

Error:

```
06-20 09:47:27.382: E/ActivityThread(324): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
06-20 09:47:27.382: E/ActivityThread(324): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
06-20 09:47:27.392: E/ActivityThread(324): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
06-20 09:47:27.702: D/dalvikvm(324): GC freed 3148 objects / 195472 bytes in 68ms
06-20 09:47:27.822: D/1:(324): Start ArrayList
06-20 09:47:27.822: I/global(324): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
06-20 09:47:27.822: D/2:(324): Read File
06-20 09:47:27.822: D/3:(324): 9.34669876098644,48.2405319213867
06-20 09:47:27.822: D/4:(324): 9.34669876098644 - 48.2405319213867
06-20 09:47:27.952: E/APP(324): Failed
06-20 09:47:27.952: E/APP(324): java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
06-20 09:47:27.952: E/APP(324):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDblImpl(Native Method)
06-20 09:47:27.952: E/APP(324):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDouble(FloatingPointParser.java:283)
06-20 09:47:27.952: E/APP(324):     at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:285)
06-20 09:47:27.952: E/APP(324):     at de.bodprod.rettinfo.BOSLstItemDetail.onCreate(BOSLstItemDetail.java:93)
06-20 09:47:27.952: E/APP(324):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-20 09:47:27.952: E/APP(324):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
06-20 09:47:27.952: E/APP(324):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
06-20 09:47:27.952: E/APP(324):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
06-20 09:47:27.952: E/APP(324):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
06-20 09:47:27.952: E/APP(324):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-20 09:47:27.952: E/APP(324):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-20 09:47:27.952: E/APP(324):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
06-20 09:47:27.952: E/APP(324):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-20 09:47:27.952: E/APP(324):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-20 09:47:27.952: E/APP(324):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
06-20 09:47:27.952: E/APP(324):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
06-20 09:47:27.952: E/APP(324):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-20 09:47:28.043: I/MapActivity(324): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
06-20 09:47:28.052: E/MapActivity(324): Couldn't get connection factory client
06-20 09:47:28.272: D/dalvikvm(324): GC freed 1440 objects / 382480 bytes in 66ms
06-20 09:47:28.292: D/AndroidRuntime(324): Shutting down VM
06-20 09:47:28.292: W/dalvikvm(324): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
06-20 09:47:28.292: E/AndroidRuntime(324): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
06-20 09:47:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(324): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 09:47:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.draw(OverlayBundle.java:42)
06-20 09:47:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onDraw(MapView.java:476)
06-20 09:47:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6535)
06-20 09:47:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
06-20 09:47:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
06-20 09:47:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
06-20 09:47:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
06-20 09:47:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6641)
06-20 09:47:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
06-20 09:47:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
06-20 09:47:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
06-20 09:47:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
06-20 09:47:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
06-20 09:47:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
06-20 09:47:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
06-20 09:47:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
06-20 09:47:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
06-20 09:47:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
06-20 09:47:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
06-20 09:47:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1830)
06-20 09:47:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1349)
06-20 09:47:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1114)
06-20 09:47:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
06-20 09:47:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-20 09:47:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-20 09:47:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
06-20 09:47:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-20 09:47:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-20 09:47:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
06-20 09:47:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
06-20 09:47:28.302: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-20 09:47:28.323: I/dalvikvm(324): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
```

**Solution:**

Now it works, i create the file with the coords in eclipse new and use this now:

```
ArrayList<GeoPoint> points = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
try{
    InputStream koord = getAssets().open("biberach");
    if (koord != null) {
        InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(koord);
        BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(input);
        String line;
        while (( line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] point_t = line.split(",");
                double y = Double.parseDouble(point_t[0]);
                double x = Double.parseDouble(point_t[1]);
                points.add(new GeoPoint((int)(x*1e6), (int)(y*1e6)));
        }
        koord.close();
        polygon = new Polygon(points);
    }
}catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("APP","Failed", e);
}
```

Was an error with the file

Comment: Which is line 42 in OverlayBundle?

Comment: are sure "points" variable is initialized ?

Comment: it looks like it can't parse given value to double (or any other number), maybe because of "." char, so change it to ",", by .replace(".", ","). for example `String value = "56456.4564".replace(".", ",");`, so try `double x = Double.parseDouble(point_t[0].replace(".", ","));` and same to y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are catching and ignoring any exceptions in that block, try logging out the exception in the empty catch area, and you'll see that you are getting a `NumberFormatException`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9.34669876098644"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:514)
    at TestParseInt.main(TestParseInt.java:4)
```

You cannot `parseInt` on a double number (and even it did work, you'd only end up with the integer portion, which is not what you want).  Try using `Double.parseDouble()` instead.

In other words

```
        double x = Double.parseDouble(point_t[0].trim());
        double y = Double.parseDouble(point_t[1].trim());
```

and instead of this

```
}catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

try using

```
}catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("APP","Failed", e);
}
```

**UPDATE1:**
Maybe ensure that you've removed whitespace so use
`split("\\s*,\\s*)` and then `.trim()` on the strings.  Double.parseDouble() should allow for whitespace, though.

**UPDATE2:**
In your `locale`, is the `decimal` a valid separator, or is a `comma`?  If so, then you may have to use `DecimalFormat` to parse the values and force a `US` locale

I see from your profile that you are in Germany, but the numbers you are parsing are not in German.  So, try this..

```
DecimalFormat parser = (DecimalFormat)DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
double x = (Double)parser.parse("48.2405319213867");
```

This forces the parser to use a US locale for parsing the number (ie, . is decimal).

Comment: +1 well taken point ......even I think where the flow went after printing D/Point:(231): 9.34669876098644 - 48.2405319213867

Comment: @DheereshSingh : can u see my answer bez i think he is spiting string in wrong way

Comment: yes Imran, but I think here Laire performing operation on each line get from buffreader ...... and the flow is also going to Log.d("4:",point_t[0] + " - " + point_t[1]); but not to  Log.d("Geopoint:",x + " - " + y); as per log cat so issue should be in between these lines.....

Comment: The Double values look good, and I parsed them on my device (just to make sure), so I'm at a loss.  You could try changing your split and parse statements to remove whitespace and see if that helps. (I updated the answer to include this)

Comment: In your locale, is a decimal a valid numeric placeholder for the "decimal" or it is a comma.  ie, would a typical double look like, "9.5" or "9,5", if it's the latter, then check out DecimalFormat (I've updated the answer to reflect this)

Comment: I don't know what i can do more... I used line.split("\\s*,\\s*"); I changed . into , I trim but I still get the error java.lang.NumberFormat.Exception

Comment: Can you try to parse using the DecimalFormat class.  (I added a sample to the answer).  Since you are in Germany, and the numbers you are parsing are in US (general statement) then that may be the issue.

Comment: That's great... but since the "fix" was the first part of my answer (ie, use Double.parseDouble), why did you accept the other answer that was simply a duplicate of mine (but was provided later??)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing wrong.as in your text file string first spilt it on the bases of **space** and then bases of **" ; "**  as:

```
    String line="";
    while (( line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
        Log.d("3: ", line);
        line +=line;
    }
    String[] point_arr = line.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i <= point_arr.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        String[] point_t = point_arr[i].split(",");
        Log.d("4:",point_t[0] + " - " + point_t[1]);
        int x = Integer.parseInt(point_t[0]);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(point_t[1]);
        Log.d("Geopoint:",x + " - " + y);
        points.add(new GeoPoint((int)(x*1e6), (int)(y*1e6)));
        Log.d("5:","saved");
    }
```

**EDIT:** or it maybe possible first split your string on the baes of **" ; "** and then bases of **space** as you put in file

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to get all lines String[]. Then,as you see, you have to split by " " (space) to get two coords and THEN those got strings split again by "," to get logtitude and latitute. So with one line you get two coords, not one

Also, this part

```
        int x = Integer.parseInt(point_t[0]);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(point_t[1]);
        Log.d("Geopoint:",x + " - " + y);
        points.add(new GeoPoint((int)(x*1e6), (int)(y*1e6)));
```

is not good, it should be:

```
        double x = Double.parseDouble(point_t[0]);
        double y = Double.parseDouble(point_t[1]);
        Log.d("Geopoint:",x + " - " + y);
        points.add(new GeoPoint((int)(x*1e6), (int)(y*1e6)));
```

because, when you have 20.123456 number, you get 20000000, while my method gets 20123456

also, before catch, add one more catch

```
catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    //this occurs when can't convert String to specified number format, so it means, that you give bad number to parse
}
```

It doesn't answer your exact question, but it helps you with your work